# Will ubuntu and games like dota 2 and league of legends work on my computer?

Tags: games

It is an acer aspire 5742g notebook:

Intel i3 2.53 mhz , 3 gb ddr 3 , hdd 500 gb , video intel hd g with 256mb ( on w7 on this graphic board run windows ) and a nvidia 520m 1gb video

Comment: On how to install lol, follow this: [League of Legends under Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/league-of-legends-under-ubuntu) All bug related issues should be asked on the lol Pol page [League Of Legends - Supported software - PlayOnLinux - Run your Windows applications on Linux easily!](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1135-League_Of_Legends.html)

Answer (score 3):

**DOTA2 RECOMMENDED HARDWARE REQUIREMENTS**

- CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo 2.4GHz
- RAM: 2 GB
- VID: DX9 Compatible + Shader Model 3 (Which is an Nvidia 7600 or ATI X1600 or better)
- HDD: 3GB Free Space. With 256MB you should be fine.
- SOUND: The BEST 2 Speaker Stereo System that comes in a Cereal Box
  (Which means whatever you have)

**LEAGUE OF LEGENDES (LOL) RECOMMENDED HARDWARE REQUIREMENTS**

- CPU: 2 GHz CPU
- RAM: 1GB
- HDD: 1.5GB
- VID: Any video card that supports Shader Model 2.0+, which mean an Nvidia GeForce 5 Series and above or an Ati 9000 series and above. With 256MB Video memory you should be fine.
- SOUND: A SUPER sound system that can play an 128 Bit MP3 song and not die out while trying (Which is to say, anything you have will play good).

As you can see, you can actually play both games with little effort. I have tested them in a Core 2 Duo 2.8Ghz and the both play excellent. LOL has an already existing way of playing it in Linux and it runs the same way as in Windows. Dota2 as seen in [this wine app review](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=24458) shows that it runs perfect. Although the review is not for Ubuntu, I already did the test and it runs perfect.

Just in case you need to make sure you have the correct Wine version installed. Just install the PPA for it as seen here http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu byt Scott Ritchie:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install wine1.5`

Answer (score 1):

What do the system requirements state for required/recommended hardware for each game? They're going to be the same as for Windows, so if it runs on the same system under Windows, then your hardware will support it under Linux, as well.

That said, the usual issues will be software-related. DirectX is a Windows proprietary graphics engine, so Linux has to emulate it. Recent versions of Wine, with updated games, do quite well on this front, but it may be hit or miss with some games, depending on how they're coded. When in doubt, look up your game on WineHQ, so you know what to anticipate.

Comment: thx for ur support i will serch winehq right now